# How can we visualise a Sine wave spatially in 3D & 4D

Tags: geometry

If possible, how can we visualise a simple Sine wave in 3D & 4D (spatial dimensions)

[image]

Does 3D become a spiral rotating around a 3rd axis?

[image]

Then how do we approach 4D ?

***Update:***

After @trula 's recommendation, here's a an attempt 'to describe what you think of, when you think of a 3d wave'

The sphere isn't to represent t, it is just tracing the idea of an oscillating surface following a 2D sine wave.

For some reason the animation has come out really fast. The sphere is following the same oscillation in radius.

[image]

Comment: What do you call a 3 d sin wave, in 3d you have sine waves as EM waves or sound waves, if you consider t as the 4th dimension these are in 4d.

Comment: I'm not sure what you are envisioning, but one can always consider for dimension $n \in \mathbb N_0$ sets of the form $\left\{(t, \sin(t +\omega_1), \ldots, \sin(t +\omega_i), \ldots, \sin(t + \omega_n)) \ | \ t \in 
 \mathbb R\right\} \subseteq \mathbb R^{n + 1}$ for any selection of $\omega \in \mathbb R^n$

Comment: @trula I understand we can consider t as the 4th dimension but I'm wondering if / how we can consider a 4th spatial dimension?

Comment: @user2628206 I would like to understand what the 4th component means. So up until 3D, from what I understand, each dimension we effectively oscillate around a new axis - x, y, z. If we consider a 4th spatial dimension how would it oscillate? both mathematically and physically (I understand it's impossible to visualise 4D but we can make approximations and projections?)

Comment: we do not effectively oscillate around axis x,y,z, in our real 3d world a sin wave oscillates around one axis, if it is a transverse wave or in the directions of traveling for sound waves. So you should try to describe what you think of, when you think of a 3d wave . It is already almost impossible to visualize a wave in 3d, Your first picture for example gives only the vibration at one point in time, if you take x instead of t it ist only the situation at one Moment, so even for a wave traveling on a 1d string you need a movie to visualize it. your spiral is not a wave in 3d.

Comment: @trula thanks! updated the post, maybe it will help

Comment: The verb _become_ in "Does 3D become..." suggests there is a unique notion of a 3D sine wave. Unfortunately, there isn't. We can view a plane sine wave as a 3D (or 4D) sine wave, for example, by viewing the plane as embedded in a higher-dimensional space. user2628206's comment gives a family of definitions that includes the helix seemingly pictured for three-space, but because the phases are free parameters there's no single answer even if that definition is qualitatively satisfactory. <> In short, it's not clear (to me) what's being asked.

Comment: I agree with @AndrewD.Hwang that it's not clear being asked. One property of the family of curves that I have given is if the first component is seen as time and the rest as space then the image of map $f: \mathbb R^{n + 1} \to \mathbb R^3$ given by $f(t,x_1,\ldots, x_n) = (t,x_i,x_j)$ for $i,j <n $ maps my curve to a curve that is like your 3d spiral. In this sense, my offering simply makes a particle oscillate sinusoidally in all of its spatial dimensions. But, there are many ways to generalise a curve to high dimensions. What is correct will depend on the phenomena you are trying to model.

Comment: I think this question has two problems: Firstly how does one visualise a curve / surface for $n > 3$ and secondly, are there any families of maps $f: \mathbb R \to \mathbb R^n$ that 'generalise'  the map $\sin$ in some sense with a given physical interpretation. Both of these questions are relatively soft and nebulas with the amount  of info you have given, making it hard to give a good answer. It is nonetheless still worth thinking about, but perhaps a discussion may be more fruitful than question and answer format?

Comment: @AndrewD.Hwang I agree, the use of becoming is misleading. I think it was becoming in respect to a change in dimension we are looking at not a change in shape

Comment: @user2628206 true, this is the issue, I'd like to explore given a finite t increasing spatial dimensions and how the sinusoidal oscillation behave in higher dimensions.. if at all. A particle oscillating sinusoidally is what I'm trying to understand.

Comment: @user2628206 I'm not sure how to approach your two points (they are what I would like to understand) which is why I don't know what information to give. Apologies, I agree a discussion format makes more sense, I realise this may not be the place/format for such a broad question.

Comment: I would suggest either talking to a lecturer or course-mates if in formal study. Otherwise opening up a  room in https://chat.stackexchange.com/ may help to get a discussion going. Personally I am a mathematician and not a physicist  so I'm not really sure what there is to  `understand' save from learning how to work with and manipulate formally  curves / surface of high dimension. I.e., I may not be the best person to help further in this discussion.